# Let H be a subgroup of Z(G). Then show that H is normal in G.

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

Hi i am kinda stuck here. How do i show that H is normal in G???

Any tips or suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: The definition of a normal subgroup: for any $h \in N$, $g \in G$, we have $ghg^{-1} \in N$. Now, if $h \in H$, then $h \in Z(G)$ and therefore $ghg^{-1} = \ldots$?

Comment: @Salman ghg^-1 is in Z(G) ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any subgroup $H$ is normal in $G$ iff $gHg^{-1} \subset H$ for all $g \in G$.   This is equivalent to $gH = Hg$ for all $g \in G$.

The latter form is what you want most likely because you're dealing with $xy = yx$ type elements in $Z(G)$.

Answer (score 1):

For a $g\in G$ you just have to show that $gH=Hg$. But the first set consists of all elements $gh, h\in H$ while the second is the set of all elements $hg, h\in H$. Now, what do you know about the $h\in H$?